# Subprocess and list comprehension in python

Tags: python

Im trying to execute the tasklist command using `subprocess.check_output`. Then taking that output (each PID) and adding it to a list.

The problem im having is that my list comprehension seems to be making the list for each digit in the PID rather than the entire PID.

Ive played around with it for a while now trying out various comprehensions ive found using google but cant get it working as id like. Im sure there's something stupid I'm doing wrong but as they "Its simple if you know how".

Any help would be appreciated

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
['1', '2', '4', '7', '2', '\n', '1', '3', '0', '2', '8', '\n']
```

**CODE**

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = 'cmd.exe /C tasklist| find "mstsc"| cut -d" " -f21'
>>> out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
>>> tasklist = [task for task in out if task != None]
>>> print tasklist
['1', '2', '4', '7', '2', '\n', '1', '3', '0', '2', '8', '\n']
>>>
```

Comment: What's the output if you `print out`?

Comment: @Michelle it is as follows; `>>> print out
12472
13028`

Comment: `split` `out` along newlines?, so instead of `out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)`, use `out=subprocess.check_output(cmd).split('\n')` or something similar

Comment: `check_output()` appears to be giving you a string, not a list? @cactus1 probably has the right idea.

Comment: @cactus1 rofl see simple ^_^ thanks. Will keep that in mind next time. Worked a treat

Comment: @cactus1 want to give an answer so I can give you the relevant kudos

Comment: Eh, I guess it'd be good for anyone else having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `subprocess.check_output(cmd)` returns a string rather than a list of strings, so you need to `split()` it to get the list you want to process using the comprehension:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'cmd.exe /C tasklist| find "mstsc"| cut -d" " -f21'
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).split('\n')
tasklist = [task for task in out if task != None]
print tasklist
```